# How do you handle the case when there is no image for a post?

Tags: ios, image, post, constraints, anchor

Let's say one's want to build programatically a **feed similar to Facebook's feed,  without using storyboards at all, using a Collection View in a View Controller.**

Users can write a new post, which would consist in a body, and if they wish, they can add an image as well. **So the collection view will be a mix of text posts and image+text posts.**

I was wondering what is **the best way to handle the case when there is no image to display, how do you handle the height of the collection view cell ?**

I created a subclass of collection view cell and inside I added some constraints. Within that subclass I added an "if statement" to check whether the postImageView.image is nil or not and update the constraints/anchors accordingly. 
The problem is that it never get called and continue behaving as if there are no images even when there actually are.

It seems like the Collection View doesn't detect the empty images and I'm suspecting it has something to do with the fact I'm using reusable cells.

**Do you have any idea of how to deal with the constraints in such a case ?**

Thank you very much for your help,

J,

Comment: from your question - "Within that subclass I added an "if statement" to check whether the postImageView.image is nil or not and update the constraints/anchors accordingly.". Can you explain in which function you are checking this and where you are checking for image nil. Because am sure you are loading image from url. So some chunk of code for the scenario will help debugging your problem. In general case we take image view's  height constraint's outlet in the cell class and we change it according to the data it is going to display.

Comment: use this [uicollectionviewflowlayout](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout), You can manage each cell item size.

Comment: Dear @MaheshAgrawal Thanks for your reply ! I'm actually just testing for now, so I'm not loading the images from a URL just yet. I am just adding an image in cellForRowAtIndexPath for some cells arbitrarily to check if everything's going well.   About the contraints and the if statement to check whether the postimage.image is nil, I added it inside the setup() of my custom collection view cell.

Comment: You said that you would "take the image view's height constraint's", do you mean in the collection view cell subclass ? But how would you know whether the postImageView's image is nil or not?

Comment: @agent_stack Thank you for your answer. I am actually already using UICollectionViewFlowLayout for my Collection View but the problem is that I'm struggling at finding the correct way to detect whether the image exists or not for a specific post cell.

Comment: @jellyfish6 can you add `cellForItem` method code work?

Comment: @agent_stack Sorry I'm not on my computer at the moment so I cannot send my cellForItem code, however the code is very simple as most of the complicated constraints stuff is inside my cell subclass. the code is basically just a let cell = collectionView.dequeue.... as! FeedCell followed by a few dummy texts and images I added to some of the posts, and then a return cell at the end, that's it :)

Comment: @jellyfish6 without checking your code work i can't help. And from where you'r fetching the feed data?

Comment: Yes, you need to take outlet of the imageView inside the collectionViewCell subclass. And about - "But how would you know whether the postImageView's image is nil or not?" - If you are receiving the image from your web service then set the height constraint to a height which you want otherwise make it 0. Use UITableViewAutomaticDimension to manage cell height automatically and control the layout of the cell with constraints every where with no extra constraint and no less constraint.

Comment: post some sample code through git for a single view controller using xcode >= 7. i will edit and show you how you can do this. i have done applications like this which are live now but i have used multiple type of cell for the complex screens and this height constraint method for simple screens.

Comment: Good afternoon @MaheshAgrawal ! I took the time to make a test project this morning to show you a basic version (without storyboards and using anchors) of my layout. Here is the link on dropbox : https://www.dropbox.com/s/9lsgl4xshmwqhy2/PostLayoutTest.zip?dl=0 inside the project I tried to explain you in the comments how I'd like my layout to work. Please feel free asking if you have any questions :) And thanks again for your help

Comment: i was a little busy with my work but i have reviewed your code. First thing is why you are not using storyboards and if that was the specified requirement then why you are trying anchors to set constraint. I use the default and standard way of allocating and adding a constraint to keep the full control within the code. Am modifying your code for the constraints. I will post the url soon for you. One more thing you took static first and second cell as image type and other as normal. So i assume those will be done by web service data. So i am taking dummy json to perform the needful.

Comment: here is your modified code. https://www.dropbox.com/s/5tzlku3gwmdu17r/PostLayoutTest.zip?dl=0 try it once. I did not modified everything but i would suggest using tableview for the kind of task you want to achieve. tell me if my solution works.

Comment: Hi and sorry for my late reply ! Thank you very much for your help. I checked the code, however I doesn't work quite as expected : as you can see on the picture, the spacing between the bottom label and the element above (either the post picture if there is, or the post text if there isn't any picture) is not the same. I'd like to achieve a layout so that the spacing between the elements remain the same, whether or not there is an image added to the post, and I'm still struggling at that. Please let me know if you can find a solution, I'm searching on my side too ! Thanks. J.

Comment: http://imageshack.com/a/img924/5039/gcQyBi.png   here is a screenshot so you can see the spacing problem that I'm talking about,